# Convergence of $\sum (-1)^k\frac{k}{e^k}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does the series $\sum (-1)^k\frac{k}{e^k}$ converge?
This series does converge absolutely because
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\left|\sum (-1)^k\frac{k}{e^k}\right| = \sum \frac{k}{e^k}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
converges by the integral test.

The function $f:[2,\infty) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) := \frac{x}{e^x} = xe^{-x}$ is continuous, positive and monotonely decreasing by examining the derivative $f'(x) = e^{-x}(1-x) < 0$ because $1-x < 0$ and $e^{-x} > 0$ for all $x\geq 2$.

Since $f(k) = ke^{-k}$, to determine whether or not the series converges it suffices to see what happens to $\int_{2}^{\infty} f(x) \; dx$. Doing so letting $u = x \Rightarrow du = dx$ and $dv = e^{-x} \; dx \Rightarrow v = -e^{-x}$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\int_{2}^{\infty} xe^{-x} \; dx &= \left[-xe^{-x}\right]_{2}^{\infty}+\int_{2}^{\infty} e^{-x} \; dx \\
&= \left(\lim_{b\to \infty} -be^{-b}+2e^{-2}\right) + \left(\lim_{b\to \infty} -e^{-b}+e^{-2}\right) \\
&= \frac{3}{e^2} > 0.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
This integral converges so by the integral test $\sum \frac{k}{e^k}$ converges as well. Hence, $\sum (-1)^k\frac{k}{e^k}$ converges. Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Alternating series test.

Comment: It's correct. But not the most elementary method. Ratio Test: Let $a_k =(-1)^k k /e^k.$ Then $|a_{k+1}/a_k|=(1/e)\frac {k+1}{k}$ converges to $1/e<1. $ Comparison Test: Let $e=1+r.$ Since $r>0,$ if $k\ge 4$ then$ k^{-1}e^k=k^{-1}(1+r)^k>$ $ k^{-1}[1+\binom {k}{1}r+\binom {k}{2}k^2+\binom {k}{3}r^3]>$ $k^{-1}\binom {k}{3}r^3=$ $(1/6)k^2(1-1/k)(1-2/k)r^3\ge$ $\ge (1/6)k^2(1-1/4)(1-2/4)r^3=$ $ k^2 \frac {r^3}{16}=$ $k^2 \frac {(e-1)^3}{16}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also in that case, as a simpler approach, by [**limit comparison test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with $\sum  \frac1{k^2}$ the series converges indeed

$$\frac{\frac{k}{e^k}}{ \frac1{k^2}}={\frac{k^3}{e^k}}\to 0$$

Comment: Is it really so much simpler? In any event, this is proved by comparison.

Comment: @qbert In many cases it is much simpler in my opinion that comparison test which involves inequalities which sometimes can lead to mistakes. Of course handle inequality properly is a good skill to have but in case of doubts I think that LCT can be a big help.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a simpler immediate answer is given by the Leibniz rule : If $\;\{a_n\}\;$ is strictly decreasing  with limit 0, then $\;a_1 - a_2 + a_3 - a_4 + ... - ...\;$ is convergent.

Comment: @user2661923 Leibniz rule in a certain sense is more advanced since it is useful when we can't use absolute convergence.

Comment: @gimusi "...is more advanced...".  Agreed.  However it is (still) plausible to me that this is what the teacher (or textbook) intended.  That is, if the series is absolutely convergent, then why ask whether the alternating series is convergent.  Further, the point of the problem may have simply been to realize that $\;a_n\;$ is going to 0.  A rebuttal argument is that in my (Apostol) Calculus textbook, the Liebniz rule is given over 100 pages after the demonstration that $\;\frac{k}{e^k}\;$ is going to 0.

Comment: It can be but in my opinion we should avoid Leibniz when it is not strictly needed. The absolute converges criterion must be used before when it suffices. Anyway we are talking mainly of personal points of view. Thanks! Bye

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but the integral test is overkill. Just by comparison, since $k\leq e^{1/2k}$ for $k\geq 1$,
$$
\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k}{e^k}\leq \sum_{k\geq 1}e^{-1/2k}=
\frac{1}{e^{1/2}-1}
$$
by summing a geometric series.